# Error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so in Java

Tags: java, linux, processing-ide

I have ElementaryOS installed. I am running Processing IDE in the terminal by running `./processing` in the `processing-3.3.4` directory. I'm getting this error:

```
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/a/58024

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest version of Processing: https://github.com/processing/processing/releases/tag/processing-0262-3.3.5

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue that is being worked on](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5111). As of this moment, it doesn't look like they have released a fix, so I would try the previous version.

---

In the future, I recommend searching with Google for the specific error you're getting before posting to a forum. It can be hard to know what to search for, so here's an explanation of my process.

First I tried searching for `"elementary os" processing cannot open shared object file "libjli.so"` but since that didn't give me anything obvious, I assumed that this is not a widespread problem with Elementary OS. Note that I put quotes around `"elementary os"` and `"libjli.so"`. This ensures that Google treats these as phrases, so pages with the word "elementary" and the word "os" will not match unless those two words are side-by-side.

Next I searched for `processing ide cannot open shared object file "libjli.so"` which gave me a link to the [main Issues page on the github project](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues). On that page, I [searched for `libjli.so`](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20libjli.so) which gave me one result, which is the issue I linked here.

I hope that helps you in the future.

Comment: Note that this has been fixed in the latest version of Processing: https://github.com/processing/processing/releases/tag/processing-0262-3.3.5

Answer (score 0):

[Download Java SE Development Kit 8u192](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) in your home directory (click "**Accept License Agreement**")

Extract (in terminal):

```
tar xzvf ~/jdk-8u192-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Create the symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -s -f ~/jdk1.8.0_192/bin/* /usr/bin/
```

Test:

```
java -version
```